# Magento2 : Too much apache processes running and consume memory

Tags: magento2, apache2

In magento2 - I've an instance of type `c5d.xlarge` on **AWS with centos 7 with `8GB` of RAM**. I'm running a magento storefront on it. **Magento version is `2.1.7` and apache version is `2.4`** . Now the problem is the memory usage is 74% and it gets out of memory sometimes, although storefront not public for users yet.

And when I've checked the processes I've found that about 100 processes are for apache `S` state, All of them has the same command of `/usr/sbin/httpd Dforeground` but with different usage of memory which range from `600MB` to `900MB`.

The question is why all those processes are running and how to choose the best processes to kill and keep storefront running?

**Note1:** CPU usage is 0%, it get in use when I open the storefront and start send requests.

**Note2:** I've checked for MPM it's `prefork` but when I open `httdp.conf` I cannot find `prefork` module or other module for MPM inside it

Comment: Hey, @yomna did you found any solution?